# Split string of concatenated digits into a numeric vector of individual values

Tags: r, string, split, casting, numeric

Suppose I have a long string of concatenated digits, `0` and `1`:

```
"1010101010101010100011011"
```

I would like to split the individual values and separate them by a `,` like so `"1,0,1,0,1,0,1,1,..."`. Then transform into a numeric vector like this:

```
c(1,0,1,0,1,...)
```

What would be a smart way to do that ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
a <- "1010101010101010100011011"

b <- unlist(strsplit(a,""))

c <- as.numeric(b)

class(c)
#> [1] "numeric"
```

Comment: For efficiency maybe use `as.integer(unlist(strsplit(a, "", fixed = TRUE)))`

Comment: True. I just  wanted to show the steps for clarity.

Comment: My comment was not about the two steps but about `fixed = TRUE` and `as.integer`

Comment: Still for efficiency, replace `unlist` with `[[1]]`, i.e. `strsplit(a, "", fixed = T)[[1]]`.

Comment: where can I find content on how to write more efficient code in R guys ? curious why certain code is more efficient than others

Answer (score 4):

A second option is

```
utf8ToInt(x) - 48L
# [1] 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 0 0 1 1 0 1 1
```

Answer (score 3):

**1) strapply** Extract each character and convert it to numeric giving a numeric vector:

```
library(gsubfn)
x <- "1010101010101010100011011"
strapply(x, ".", as.numeric, simplify = c)
## [1] 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 0 0 1 1 0 1 1
```

If you have a vector of such strings then this could be used to produce a list of numeric vectors:

```
xx <- c(x, x)
strapply(xx, ".", as.numeric)
```

**2) scan** Insert a space after each character and then scan it in giving a numeric vector. `x` is defined in (1).

```
scan(text = gsub("(.)", "\\1 ", x), quiet = TRUE)
## [1] 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 0 0 1 1 0 1 1
```

**3) read.fwf** Read it in as fixed fields having width of 1 giving a data frame. `x` is defined in (1).

```
read.fwf(textConnection(x), widths = rep(1, nchar(x)))
##   V1 V2 V3 V4 V5 V6 V7 V8 V9 V10 V11 V12 V13 V14 V15 V16 V17 V18 V19 V20 V21
## 1  1  0  1  0  1  0  1  0  1   0   1   0   1   0   1   0   1   0   0   0   1
##   V22 V23 V24 V25
## 1   1   0   1   1
```

Answer (score 2):

Another option (following the steps you've described), first inserting `,`:

```
x <- gsub("(?!^|$)", ",", x, perl = TRUE)

x

[1] "1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,0,0,1,1,0,1,1"
```

And then using `scan` for transforming into your integer vector:

```
scan(text = x, what = 0L, sep = ",", quiet = TRUE)

[1] 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 0 0 1 1 0 1 1
```

Comment: Maybe `x` should be assigned to the argument `text` in `scan`, or it'll get an error. I.e. `scan(text = x, what = 0L, sep = ",", quiet = TRUE)`.